# Powering two loads from either one or two sources

Tags: power, mosfet, switches

Both loads need to be powered at all times - V1 or V2 can be either both present or only one of them. Does this circuit look like it is going to make it happen?
Instead of M1 and M2 there will probably be power switch ICs enabled / disabled by a microcontroller.

[image]

Comment: Are you missing some connections to the gates of the MOSFETs?

Comment: What's going to happen if V1 and V2 are not equal or one has failed?

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy indeed

Comment: @Transistor I do not know, bad things I presume. Any way around it without the use of diodes ?

Comment: I think what @Transistor is getting at is that if V1 is not equal to V2, then whichever source is higher voltage will try to charge the lower one through the body diode of the MOSFETs.

Comment: What is the required current?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another way, using two Schottky diodes.

[image]

Two microcontroller - driven electromagnetic relays or solid state switches may be used instead of the toggle switches.

Since either of the power sources is to be capable of catering to both the loads, it is clear that two are required for redundancy and not for total power output.

For that purpose, a small difference in output voltages is a distinct advantage since the one with the higher voltage will be the primary source and the other the back-up.

Comment: Depends how the load should be shared. The asker's circuit is apparently intended to power one load from each source if both sources are online. This one will use the one with the highest voltage (due to manufacturing tolerances)

Comment: @user253751 OR-ing diodes are the last resort. I would like to avoid their high voltage drop and emanated heat.

Comment: @user253751 - Hi, My answer has been edited in response to your comment.

Comment: @kellogs - Hi, Isn't the total load less than 3 W ?